How to send nested form data using applications like apidog
I have developed route in NestJs, requiring nested data sending such as address of coffeeshop which own self needs street, state, postal cod and ...
how could I send the owned field datas to end point? is it possible? what is the way?..
here is my dtos :
export class ShopAddressDTO {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    street: string;
  
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    city: string;
  
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    state: string;
  
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsPostalCode('any') // Adjust for a specific locale if needed
    postalCode: string;
  
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => GeoLocationDTO)
    geoLocation: GeoLocationDTO;
  }
...

export class CreateShopTableDto 
{
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber({})
    tableNumber: number;
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber({})
    capacity:number
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsEnum(TableStatus)
    status:TableStatus
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsBoolean()
    is_active:boolean

}
...
export class CreateShopDto{
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    name:string
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    bio:string
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(()=>ShopAddressDTO)
    address:ShopAddressDTO
    @IsOptional()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    is_active:boolean
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsUUID()
    owner:string
    @IsArray()
    @ValidateNested({each:true})
    @Type(()=>CreateShopTableDto)
    tables:CreateShopTableDto[]
}

then how could I send the nested fields to endpoint using apidog or postman or...
